# match url root but not the files inside

Tags: regex

I am creating  sharepoint crawl rule to ignore some urls on the crawling process.

I want to ignore this:

```
http://mysite1.com/sites/12345678
```

But I dont want to ignore the rest of the files inside

```
http://mysite1.com/sites/12345678/documentlibrary1/doc1.docx
etc,etc
```

As I am not an expert with regular expressions I am asking this here.
I know the site url always uses 8 characters so that could help

any help is appreciated

Comment: Is the base always: `http://mysite1.com/sites/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex can be:

```
^http:\/\/mysite1\.com\/sites\/.{8}\/.+$
```